# Identity in Markov Process

Tags: markov-process

I want to know if my reasoning here is correct, it seems simple enough but I just want clarification (I am considering the proof that if a Markov process satisfies the detailed balance condition, then it is reversible).

If $X_{t}$ is a discrete state space Markov process, let $\pi_{x}^{(n)} = P(X_{n} = x)$, $\pi$ be the stationary distribution and $P(X_{n+1}=y|X_{n}=x) = P_{xy}$.

Then,

$P(X_{n} = x |X_{n+1}=y) = \large\frac{P(X_{n+1}=y|X_{n}=x)P(X_{n}=x)}{P(X_{n+1}=y)} = \frac{P_{xy}P(X_{n}=x)}{P(X_{n+1}=y)} = \large\frac{P_{xy}\pi_{x}}{\pi_{y}}$.

It is the last equality that isn't quite so obvious to me.

Can I justfiy it by saying that infact:

$\large\frac{P_{xy}P(X_{n}=x)}{P(X_{n+1}=y)} = \large\frac{P_{xy}\pi_{x}^{(n)}}{\pi_{y}^{(n+1)}}$,

but since $\pi^{(n)} \rightarrow \pi$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and since 
$P(X_{n} = x |X_{n+1}=y)$ is constant, I can let $n \rightarrow \infty$ in the above, so that

$\large\frac{P_{xy}\pi_{x}^{(n)}}{\pi_{y}^{(n+1)}} =\large\frac{P_{xy}\pi_{x}}{\pi_{y}}$?

Thanks for your insight and thoughts.